# .Net Reflector VS Plugin, change language representation?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-reflector

RedGate's **.Net Reflector** for desktop has an option to set the language representation between VB.Net, C#, MSIL, and others.

But default language representation for the **.Net Reflector VS** plugin is C#.

There is a way to set the language to VB.Net?.

Comment: Why not ask this in the dedicated Reflector Forum over at Red-Gate? They're pretty responsive there: https://forums.red-gate.com/viewforum.php?f=179

Comment: Btw as far as I can tell there is no option to influence the decompilation language.

Comment: Just because I'm using a trial, I imagine that they does not offer support for trial users as I've seen the same thing in other companies, then just to save my time I ask here. Thanks for comment

Comment: Try 'm. My experience is that they're great, especially in trial mode.